# "We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context" was added to this question

Tags: discussion, post-notices

The following automated response was given to [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503977/looking-for-a-succinct-way-to-describe-a-book-one-can-never-grow-tired-of-readin) *question*:

> We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

If this response can be applied to *questions* as well as *answers*, shouldn't the text be changed from *answers* to *posts*?

I'm not marking this as a bug or feature request yet, as I'm first trying to determine the rationale behind having this apply to questions as well as answers. If it should apply to both, then I'd think the message text should be altered. (I'm not sure how often this would apply to questions; this is the first time I've seen it in such a context.)

---

**Update**: Thank you for the duplication. None of my searches before I posted this, based on the wording of the message, turned up that question.

Comment: No need to change it, this makes sense as it is - we're looking for long answers _to this question_ as opposed to implying a particular answer lacks substance.

Comment: @ArtOfCode But the reply was added underneath the *question*, not underneath an *answer*. It seems as if it was triggered because the question itself was too short. If that weren't the reason, then it would be added to *every* question, regardless of the question length.

Comment: @Jason they aren't added automatically, if you look at the timeline for the question you'll see the moderator tchrist added it: https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/503977/timeline

Comment: @PeterJ I always assumed it was automated. But even if it isn't, is the *wording* appropriate for a question rather than an answer?

Comment: To me it seems odd for that post notice to have been applied to that particular English Language & Learning question.  I think you should take that up with their Meta but I agree that the post notice wording seems only to work with answers not questions - hence why I think it is a duplicate.

Comment: @PolyGeo Cheers. I have asked for specific clarification [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13288/im-questioning-this-odd-post-notice).

Comment: @JasonBassford The wording is appropriate, yes. It can apply to both questions and answers. To a question, it implies "answers to this question must have some substance". To an answer, it implies "this answer doesn't contain enough detail".

Comment: @ArtOfCode To me, it reads like a criticism of the question but with the wrong noun. The location of the text, underneath the post, is the same as where other comments about posts go. Such comments are typically positive or negative, or they seek some kind of clarification. What you're saying is that you consider it to be an *instruction* rather than feedback. While I can understand this interpretation, it's not a natural interpretation for me.